# Declare UIViewController without Knowing Subclass?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, declaration

Lets say I have a UIViewController subclass called `ViewControllerOne` and another `ViewControllerTwo`.

I know the at one point that the class I need in another method is either one of these. Is it possible to pass the class in a method, then inside that method which its received at, declare a UIViewController with whichever subclass was passed?

I want to know if its possible without just doing something like, if this = this, declare view one, else declare view two.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method could be:

```
- (void)myMethod:(Class)class {
    UIViewController *controller = [[class alloc] init];
}
```

Or something to that effect.

Or you could create the controller where you know what the class is and pass it into the method:

```
UIViewController *controller = [[MYViewController alloc] init];
[self myMethod:controller];
```

And then if need be inside the method:

```
- (void)myMethod:(UIViewController *)controller {
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[MYViewController class]]) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

Josh, besides George's answer, if I understand you right, you should be aware about the following method that every `NSObject`has:

```
- (BOOL)isKindOfClass:(Class)aClass
```

So, you can check this way

```
if ([myObject isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerOne class]])
{
     //declare here ViewControllerOne
     ViewControllerOne *myViewControllerOne = myObject;
}
else if ([myObject isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerTwo class]])
{
     //declare here ViewControllerOne
     ViewControllerTwo *myViewControllerOne = myObject;
}
```